# Missing Terraform provider? What am I doing wrong? (Terraform v0.13.5)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

As you can see below, I'm trying to pass a specific provider to a module, which then passes it as the main provider `(aws = aws.some_profile)` to a second, nested module.

on `terraform plan` I get the following error:

`Error: missing provider module.module_a.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].some_profile`

I must be doing somethig basic wrong or assuming the language works in a way that it doesn't. Ideas?

File structure:

```
├── main.tf
├── module_a
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── module_b
│       └── main.tf
└── providers.tf
```

main.tf (top level):

```
module "module_a" {
    source = "./module_a"
    providers = {
        aws.some_profile = aws.some_profile
    }
}
```

main.tf (inside module_a):

```
module "module_b" {
    source = "./module_b"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.some_profile
    }
}
```

main.tf (inside module b):

```
resource "null_resource" "null" {}
```

providers.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.22.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
    profile = "default"
    region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
    alias = "some_profile"
    profile = "some_profile"
    region = "us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: Why do you need non default provider for your module? usually There are two main reasons to use the providers argument in the module:

Using different default provider configurations for a child module.
Configuring a module that requires multiple configurations of the same provider.

Comment: I'm passing a non default provider so that it can be used as a default provider, as you mentioned, in the "grandchild" module.

Comment: Did you run terraform init before terraform apply?

Comment: Yes. This response requires 15 characters so that's what this sentence is for.

Comment: Also `terraform providers` is your friend. It will show you providers that you passing to submodules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after getting some answers on Reddit, it looks like although you are passing providers down to submodules you still need to declare said providers in each submodule like so:

```
provider "aws" { alias = "some_provider" }
```

And it seems like the terraform "required providers" block is only required on the very top level. However, if it isn't working you can try adding it to each submodule as well.

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: This 100% works for me, however it flatly contradicts the official doco at https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html. But as soon as I remove that placeholder within the module, I get "Error: Provider configuration not present". Terraform really need to clarify this.